# ngDialog modal closes on click

Tags: angularjs, ng-dialog

I want to open a form in modal, where user can input few things and that stuff will be saved in backend. I came across this [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/XDlzLtavZD3W2oWN1FQt) which implements this thing.

But when i try to click anywhere to make an input, modal closes. I tried this in my local system as well - same behavior.

Tried following things but no result:

1. I used `ngDialog.openConfirm` but it doesn't allow me to click anywhere(only tabs work.)
2. Set `closeByEscape` to `false` - escape blocked but click makes modal disappear
3. Set `closeByDocument` to `false` - clicks disabled and only tab allowed

Basically i need a modal:

1. Which doesn't disappear on click and escape
2. Allows tabs and clicks to make input
3. Doesn't disappear on click in background
4. Calls some function when submit is clicked
5. Closes only when default close button is clicked

Comment: I am not sure but it seems that the style that you are using is broken. I could manually fix it by properly setting the z-index on the overlay and form. Maybe use another library? 

This works but it uses a different library. http://plnkr.co/edit/D0WPT1?p=preview

Comment: Great Thanks. This looks really helpful. The only reason i was not looking in ui-bootstrap lib was the amount of boilerplate code required. But ngDialog lib doesn't seem to have great doc and have seen its many SO Qs unanswered. Time to switch.